# Is it possible to store a variant record to a generic type in Ada?

Tags: generics, record, ada

I have a generic library that reads data from a socket. See code listing at the end of the question.

This works fine when `My_Type` is a fixed size type, but trying to read a variant record using this code raises a `STORAGE ERROR` with the message `object too large`.

I know it's possible to send variant records over sockets since I've had an example working. I assume that the problem lies with the fact that I'm storing the record to a generic type. The exception is raised regardless of whether the variant record has a default discriminant. Is there a way of storing the variant record in this scenario?

reader_pkg.ads

```
with Sockets; use Sockets;
with Sockets.Stream_IO; use Sockets.Stream_IO;

generic
  My_Type: private
package Reader_Pkg is
  task type Receive_Task_Type is
    entry Start(FD: Socket_FD);
  end Receive_Task_Type;
end Reader_Pkg;
```

reader_pkg.adb

```
package body Reader_Pkg is
  task body Receive_Task is
    Recv_Socket: Socket_FD;
    Recv_Stream: aliased Socket_Stream_Type;
  begin
    select
      accept Start (FD : Socket_FD) do
        Recv_Socket := FD;
        Initialize (Recv_Stream, Recv_Socket);
        declare
          Message: My_Type := My_Type'Input(Recv_Stream'Access); -- STORAGE_ERROR raised here
        begin
          -- Message gets processed here
        end;
      end Start;
    or
      terminate;
    end select;
  end Receive_Task;
end Reader_Pkg;
```

Comment: Your code can't be *very* like that, since it couldn't possibly compile! I don't believe that the presence of a default discriminant would make a difference, since `'Input` first reads the discriminant(s), then prepares a data area to receive the data as indicated, then reads the data. Are you writing the data using `'Output`? (`'Write` doesn't output the discriminants; reader and writer must match.) What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: More information is needed about "My_Type". What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @Simon - Well spotted, that was a mistake I made while stripping the code down before posting. In my actual code, the Message: My_Type := My_Type'Input(Recv_Stream'Access); line does come before the begin. I've edited my question to include the full package code as it might make it easier to understand the problem.

I am using My_Type'Output to write the data.

When the package is initialised with a type of known_size, the code works as expected. When it's initialised with a variant record, a STORAGE_ERROR is raised.

I'm using GNAT 4.6 on Debian Wheezy 32 bit.

Comment: Have you tried making the package non-generic, just to see if it works?  (That is, manually replacing My_Type in the generic with the actual type.)  That could help narrow down the problem.  If that works, then there's some issue with how the compiler handles the `'Input` function on this kind of variant record.  But if you still get the same problem, then the problem could have something to do with how the stream is handled, or with socket I/O, or something.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the stream-related code; I made an [example at Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34783908/Ada/sm.adb) which works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said the problem happens whether or not the type has default discriminants, but I think this may be related to [ARM 3.7(28)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-7.html#p28):

> If a discriminated type has default_expressions for its discriminants,
>   then unconstrained variables of the type are permitted, and the values
>   of the discriminants can be changed by an assignment to such a
>   variable. If defaults are not provided for the discriminants, then all
>   variables of the type are constrained, either by explicit constraint
>   or by their initial value; the values of the discriminants of such a
>   variable cannot be changed after initialization.

If you declare a type like

```
type Rec (Len : Natural) is record
   Data : String (1 .. Len);
end record;
```

then an instance, once created, has a fixed value of `Len`. However, if you say

```
type Rec (Len : Natural := 4) is record
   Data : String (1 .. Len);
end record;
```

then the value of `Len` in an instance can be changed (only by assignment to the whole object), which means (for GNAT; some other compilers do this differently) that the compiler has to reserve enough space on the stack for the largest possible value; and in this case that means reserving enough space for a string of length 2^31 - 1. Which isn't going to work.

GNAT will warn you about this problem at compile time if you compile with additional warnings enabled (I use `-gnatwa`, which is all common warnings). Run time detection should be improved by using `-fstack-check`.

In the case above, GNAT said

```
sm.adb:20:09: warning: creation of "Rec" object may raise Storage_Error
```

One way of avoiding the problem may be to tell the compiler that you won't be assigning to the object:

```
Message: constant My_Type := My_Type'Input(Recv_Stream'Access);
         ^^^^^^^^
```

and another (which doesn't expect the compiler to be smart enough to recognise the situation) is to limit the maximum possible size:

```
subtype Length is Natural range 0 .. 1024;
type Rec (Len : Length := 4) is record
   Data : String (1 .. Len);
end record;
```

Comment: The solution turned out to be limiting the size of the discriminant and providing a default value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, the compiler doesn't "have" to reserve enough space for the largest possible discriminant value, although that's what GNAT does.  There are compilers that implement this sort of record type by dynamic allocation, and then reallocating when the discriminant changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is. Actually saving is the easy part, loading is a bit more tricky because the discriminant acts as a part of the type; that is to say you cannot have unconstrained variables laying around. It's the same problem as `S : String;` the compiler cannot use such a variable because it cannot know how much memory to allocate for it.

One way to get around this problem is to use an access-type, because we **can** have accesses to unconstrained types. Below is such a solution.

```
Pragma Ada_2012;
Pragma Assertion_Policy( Check );

With
System,
Text_Count,
Unchecked_Deallocation,     
Ada.Strings.Fixed,
Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams;

Procedure Test is

Type Boolean_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Boolean
  with Pack, Component_Size => 1;    

Type Varient_Record( Length : Positive:= 3 ) is record
    Data : Boolean_Array(1..Length):= (others => True);
end record;

Test : constant Varient_Record:=
          (Data => (True, False, False), others => <>);

Function Associate( Name : String;
            Mode : Ada.Text_IO.File_Mode ) 
    Return Ada.Text_IO.File_Type is
Use Ada.Text_IO;
begin
Return Result : File_Type do
    Open(
      File  => Result,
      Name  => Name,
      Mode  => Mode
    );
end return;
End Associate;


Begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting Test:");

    SAVE:
    declare
        Test_File : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type:= 
          Associate( "testing.txt", Ada.Text_IO.Out_File);
        Test_Stream : Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream_Access:=
          Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream( Test_File );
    begin
        Varient_Record'Write( Test_Stream, Test );
            -- Needs an end-line or something to avoid END_ERROR on read.
        String'Write( Test_Stream, ASCII.CR & ASCII.LF );
        Ada.Text_IO.Close( Test_File );
    end SAVE;

    LOAD:
    declare
        Type Access_Varient is Access Varient_Record;
        Procedure Free is new Unchecked_Deallocation(
            Object => Varient_Record,
            Name   => Access_Varient
            );
        Loaded : Access_Varient:= New Varient_Record'(others=><>);
        Test_File : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type:= 
              Associate( "testing.txt", Ada.Text_IO.In_File);
        Test_Stream : Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream_Access:=
          Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream( Test_File );
    begin
        Varient_Record'Read( Test_Stream, Loaded.All );

        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "Test and Loading are" &
              (if Test /= Loaded.All then " NOT " else " ") & 
            "the same." );

        Free(Loaded);

    Ada.Text_IO.Close( Test_File );
    End LOAD;


    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Testing complete.");
End Test;
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use `'Write`, `'Read` on discriminated types! What would happen if you only wrote a record with `Length` 2? That's why `'Input` is a function, so you an initialize by assignment. Also, if you have to write an extra CRLF something is seriously wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your code this way. Here, message is declared after the begin which is illegal.

You could however use something like:

```
declare
  Recv_Socket : Socket_FD;
  Recv_Stream : aliased Socket_Stream_Type;
begin
  -- maybe init your stream here
  declare
    Message : My_Type := My_Type'Input(Recv_Stream'Access);
  begin
    DoSomethingWithMessage(Message);
  end;
end;
```

If `My_Type` has a variable width, you must know the size of the instance you are using when you declare it, and giving an initial value is one way of specifying the size of the variable.

Comment: Declaring Message after the begin statement was a mistake which I introduced when stripping down the code to post it. The code I'm actually working with is almost identical to your example. I've now edited the question to clarify this. Sorry for any inconvenience.